# Using plastic drums for long term sour aging?

Tags: aging, sour, plastic

I have 15 gallon plastic drums, like what LME comes in. I would really like to use them to age my sours in but I'm concerned with O2 permeability. Has anyone tried this or have any good resources on types of plastic/permeability...

Comment: I've never done it, but a Google search for 'oxygen permeability of plastics' turns up dozens of results with permeability rates for various plastics. Your bucket is probably either LDPE or HDPE. Look on the bottom of the bucket, by the recycling symbol, to confirm. Or, see what recycling # it is if it doesn't say. You may also want to look into the plastic's compatibility with acids since you're storing sour beer, which will have a markedly lower pH than normal beer.

Comment: Also it seems to be a [*sensitive topic*](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/f163/oxygen-permeability-plastic-298055/) on the HomeBrewTalk forums. All the links I found to primary sources in that thread were dead, though.

Answer (score 1):

According to the guys at [this sour-only brewery](http://thebrewingnetwork.com/shows/1102) they use only glass, stainless or wood. Plastic lets in too much oxygen, leading to acetic acid.

Also, the shape of a barrel allows them to eliminate the air space above the beer by topping up periodically with fermented beer.

BTW that link is a 3-1/2 hour podcast,  but I'm 95% confident the content is in there somewhere.